# Convert postfix to postfix with Math Priorities

Tags: algorithm

Imagine we have a postfix string like this :

```
A B C + D * +
```

It's obvious that we should calculate `(B+C)` first, then `((B+C)*D)` and in the end `((B+C)*D)+A`

Now I want to convert my postfix to this postfix :

```
B C + D * A +
```

that here, everything is in order and I can start calculating from left to right without worrying about Math Priorities.

Can I do it with a stack or a tree?

Comment: Do you have - and / operators or just commuative operators (+ and *). And also is ```(45+3*36*+ == ((4+5)*3) + (3*6))``` what you call an expression where everything is in order?) Because at some point you have ```(45)36*+``` where you have to consider ```36*``` before the addition...

Comment: there is no priority when using the postfix, this is the advantage of the notation, when you reach an operator you apply it on the last two pushed values and the result is pushed too. At the end of a valid expression you have only one value on the stack and it is the result. So, you do not have to convert to compute right